# Realizar un Group By con C# y Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Hola soy un poco nuevo en esto,

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es un `Group By` a una lista que regreso a mi vista.

Quiero agrupar por `id_levantamiento`

**Mi código**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string Usuario = "";
        Usuario = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"].ToString();


        List<WebGridLevatamientos> list = new List<WebGridLevatamientos>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.tbl_levantamiento
                     join b in dc.Cat_Proyecto on a.ProyectoID equals b.ID
                     where a.Usuario == Usuario
                     //group a by a.id_levantamiento into idGroup
                     select new WebGridLevatamientos
                     {
                         Id_Levantamiento = a.id_levantamiento,
                         ProyectoId = b.Nombre_Proyecto,
                         FechaImagen = a.FechaImagen
                     });
            list = v.ToList();
        }

        return View("../Levantamiento/FiltroLevantamiento", list);
    }
```

Estuve investigando en la web pero hasta ahora no me ha funcionado nada

Saludos

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta , revisa porfa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes intentar esto:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string Usuario = "";
        Usuario = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"].ToString();


        List<WebGridLevatamientos> list = new List<WebGridLevatamientos>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            list  = (from a in dc.tbl_levantamiento
                     join b in dc.Cat_Proyecto on a.ProyectoID equals b.ID
                     where a.Usuario == Usuario
                     group a by new { a.id_levantamiento } into grupo
                     select new WebGridLevatamientos
                     {
                         Id_Levantamiento = a.id_levantamiento,
                         ProyectoId = b.Nombre_Proyecto,
                         FechaImagen = a.FechaImagen
                     }).ToList();
        }

        return View("../Levantamiento/FiltroLevantamiento", list);
    }
```

Agrega el `Group by` por `id_levantamiento` en el `Where` agregue el `new` para definir por cual campo va a realizar la agrupación.

Comment: me sale el siguiente error:     No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<<anonymous type: string Id_Levantamiento>, Inca_WEB.Models.WebGridLevatamientos>>' en 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Inca_WEB.Models.WebGridLevatamientos>'

Comment: ok dejame modifico la respuesta

Comment: o vale te agradezco de ante mano

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta , revisa porfa

Comment: uff ahora salen varios errores como este: =>  El nombre 'a' no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: @Morquecho Discúlpame se me había olvidado agregar el `into grupo`

Comment: amigo te agradezco mucho por tu apoyo ya pude resolverlo, agrego como quedo

Answer (score 2):

Así lo resolví

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string Usuario = "";
        Usuario = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"].ToString();


        List<WebGridLevatamientos> list = new List<WebGridLevatamientos>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.tbl_levantamiento
                     join b in dc.Cat_Proyecto on a.ProyectoID equals b.ID
                     where a.Usuario == Usuario
                     group a by new { a.id_levantamiento, b.Nombre_Proyecto} into grupo
                     select new WebGridLevatamientos
                     {
                         Id_Levantamiento = grupo.Key.id_levantamiento,
                         ProyectoId = grupo.Key.Nombre_Proyecto,
                         FechaImagen = grupo.Select(x => x.FechaImagen).FirstOrDefault()
                     });
            list = v.ToList();
        }
        return View("../Levantamiento/FiltroLevantamiento", list);
    }
```

Como hago un join dentro de el group agrego a y b para en el select para poder agruparlo

Comment: Por favor considera agregar una explicación, que indique como esto resuelve tu pregunta